# My mobile website is getting horizontal scroll

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design

Im makin' a mobile website for a friend - and im using media queries to adjust her website for a more mobile feeling when watching it on any smartphone.

Feels like im done with the webpage - but when i view it on my phones iphone 3gs and htc incredbile S its like that you can scroll 2-3 pixels horizontally.
Some element is messing with this and im growing gray hair since i can't really find out which it is.

how do i solve this?

webpage link

http://www.linaahlen.se/

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look with the inspector in Chrome and it looks like it's this property:

```
div.entry {
    padding: 0em 1em;
}
```

Line 106 of style-responsive.css - it's pushing the content just a few pixels wide, changing it to be `padding: 0 0.8em;` worked for me.

Oh, and just for the record, it's scrolling horizontally, not vertically!

Comment: Oh - my bad. i meant horizontally.
I've tried to replace the value... still im able to scroll just a few pixels horizontally on my phone :(

Answer (score 0):

Late, but for future reference.
I would like to point out the way to go searching the cause for the problem.
Open the site using [Google Chrome Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode). Then check to see that the problem exists there (this solution relies on the problem to show up in the Device mode). Then start setting "display: none" to the elements one by one starting from larger elements like header, content container and check after hiding each element if the unwanted scrollability has dissapeared. This way you can track down the cause of the problem.

I had the same problem and tried to identify the cause at first by looking at the CSS code of every single element, wasted a lot of time and didn't find the cause. Probably a browser can render a page better that a human reading CSS...